# How can i make sure my BLE peripheral (NRF52832) gets reconnected again after i have unpaired it?

Tags: embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy, wireshark, packet-sniffers, nrf52

A little new to NRF52, so please pardon if this turns out to be a noob question. I'm using nrf52832 as a peripheral and loading the standard SDK peripheral example of GATTS ( any other does result in the same).
After configuring that device i try to connect my phone to it , which happens succesfully. But after unpairing my phone and trying to configuring again my phone cant pair with the device. 
Phone shows:
Could'nt pair .Check settings of this device.

Sniffer shows:
Rcvd pairing failed: Pairing not supported.
I do understand that some thing is getting stored in persistent memory. So how do i remove it or how do i load that data again.

Mobile app Logs:
Error 22 (0x16) GATT_CONN TERMINATE LOCAL HOST

Comment: Are you using one of the Nordic development boards or is this a custom board? Also, do you have a debugger attached? I believe settings are stored in a section of flash so if you use the nRFgo Studio app or something to erase the entire chip and then reflash the softdevice and everything else, you should be able to get back to square one so you can debug the issue.

Comment: Hi @LaneL, 
I am using nordic dvk 52832 and i can erase the whole device and get my output. Kind of familiar with that, but is there a way i dont have to erase my whole device just to pair again?

Comment: You might be able to use the nrfjprog command line tool to clear just the settings section of flash. (I think they call it the bootloader settings page). Sounds like you're going to have to debug the code to figure out what is going on here.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've triggered one of the default security features of the nRF.

The nRF knows it has an encryption key with the phone (as it's been paired before), but the phone doesn't know the key (because you unpaired it and it deleted the key), so the nRF assumes someone is trying to spoof the real phone and drops the connection as defense.

Not sure which nRF SDK you're using, but if you search for peer_manager in the initialisation routine you should see an option to allow keys to be over-written.

Here's the relivent [docs](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.sdk5.v12.0.0%2Fgroup__peer__manager.html). One quick-fix, if security isn't a concern, is to delete all bonding info on the nRF with `pm_peers_delete()`